# How to get user email id using hello.js?

Tags: javascript, html, hello.js

I am trying to login website with `hello.js.` I get the user name but I can't get user email id. How can I get this?

I am following [this link](http://adodson.com/hello.js/#hellojs).

This is my code :

```
<script src="hello.js" ></script>

<script>

hello.init({
    google: "742850147964-r4pfusmgmp2mtfbngh387e30k3692p79.apps.googleusercontent.com"  
}, {redirect_uri: 'index.php'});

hello.on('auth.login', function(auth) {

    // Call user information, for the given network
    hello(auth.network).api('/me').then(function(r) {       
        console.log("r.email = "+r.email);
        console.log("r.name== = "+r.name);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Create an online demo to show it. May be you made some syntax mistake.

Comment: can't see it. Where?

Comment: @emrah Thank you . I am update my code.

Comment: Why do you import hello js twice? It causes error.

Comment: And you don't ask for email! Add your demo link to question please.

Comment: How to ask email address ?

Comment: When google auth opens you need to ask permission to get email from user. Search it on google i am sure it must be pretty easy. I don't know in detail. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my problem solved by simple changing in the hello.js.

for google :-

```
scope: {                
        basic: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me profile',
       }
```

to

```
scope: {                
        basic: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
       }
```

for facebook :-

```
scope: {                
        basic: 'public_profile',
       }
```

to

```
scope: {                
        basic: 'public_profile,email',
       }
```

Comment: Great. As i said it is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

First, please keep just one js file ref, you don't need both:

```
<script src="hello.js" ></script>
<script src="hello.min.js" ></script>
```

I tried adding the button for google and it worked, I think something is wrong with the configuration for Yahoo, check if the client id is correct.

[image]